# Best lightweight PHP/MySQL forum with spam-protection

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script, mysql, forum, spam-prevention

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Forum Software should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25771/what-forum-software-should-i-use)

I have already searched and checked out posts like [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4891/whats-the-best-free-forum-software-out-there-right-now) and [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6983/suggestions-of-internet-forum-software) but it isn't what I'm looking for.

I'm looking for a lightweight PHP/MySQL forum with decent (good) anti spam functionalities.

I have been using punBB which is light and fast but doesn't stop billions of spammers to post boring links, I have tested PHPBB which I found really heavy (and it doesn't stop spammers either).

I'd like the possibility to receive a mail to 'accept' new inscriptions, auto-shut down inscriptions that have never posted (after some time) and so on and a captcha at inscription time (if it is easily modifyable that would be a plus), (public) blacklists and/or adaptive filters to stop spam would be nice too.

Does this exist in any free/cheap forum?

Answer (score 2):

[phpBB](http://www.phpbb.com/) has the features you describe. You can make new posts go to a "moderation queue". It also has prune user functionality and I'm pretty sure there is captcha integration as well.

You won't find a forum "lighter" than phpBB that has those sort of features.

Comment: Thanks, I'll wait a bit though before accepting. ("you never know").

Answer (score 1):

You could try the son of Wordpress, [bbPress](http://bbpress.org/).

It is pretty light and straightforward. For enhanced functionality just look for plug-ins and add-ons.

Comment: seems nice and light but does it have a good anti spam protection, ie. does the plugins actually exist and work well? I'm checking it out but nothing beats real experience :-)

Answer (score 1):

While I can absolutely second the suggestions of [PHPBB](http://www.phpbb.com/) and [BBPress](http://bbpress.org/), I've had better experiences with [SMF](http://www.simplemachines.org/) and, in my personal experience, have found it to be somewhat lighter than the alternatives.

While it doesn't have amazing anti-spam features out-of-the-box it does have the basic email validation and signup CAPTCHA features you'd expect and there is an [Akismet plugin](http://custom.simplemachines.org/mods/index.php?mod=544) that works very nicely. I've had an extremely good experience with Akismet on the Wordpress platform and so far it's saved two of my forums from massive spam problems, so I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

I love [UseBB](http://www.usebb.net/).

Comment: Seems nice, I'll check it out (at least it has inbuilt anti spam for registration!)